# How to call a variable in a command

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, netapp

I'm trying to write a script to accept a list of user names and assign each one a quota on a netapp storage box invoking a netapp command within a PowerShell script as per below:

```psh
$names = @("AD\test1", "AD\test2")
foreach ($user in $names) {
    $target = $user
    Invoke-NcSsh -Command 'volume quota policy rule create -vserver FS-ONE -policy-name default -volume testdaffy -type user -target $target -qtree "" -user-mapping off -disk-limit 5MB -soft-disk-limit 3MB -threshold 5MB'
}
```

Running the command gives the following errors:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> C:\Users\user\Desktop\add_quota.ps1

Error: command failed: User name $target not found. Reason: general failure.
Error: command failed: User name $target not found. Reason: general failure.
```

How do I get the variable $target to be recognised within the command I invoke so that for each loop it accepts a different user from my list?

**Resolved by using double quotes:**

```
Invoke-NcSsh -Command "volume quota policy rule create -vserver FS-ONE -policy-name default -volume testdaffy -type user -target $target -qtree """" -user-mapping off -disk-limit 5MB -soft-disk-limit 3MB -threshold 5MB"
```

Comment: The issue is your quotes. You have single quotes which dont allow the variable to expand. I understand you have them because of the double quotes. Can you switch those to single instead? Or escape them by doubling them up. `-qtree ''` or `-qtree """"`

Comment: To add to Matt's suggestions, drop $target altogether, it's not needed.  $user already has the username.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I have tried both suggestions re quotes but still get the same error....I have also removed the $target and use $user instead but still get the same error - except this time telling me $user not found...

Comment: I have resolved this after looking at your suggestions again by using doiuble quotes :Invoke-NcSsh -Command "volume quota policy rule create -vserver FS-ONE -policy-name default -volume testdaffy -type user -target $target -qtree """" -user-mapping off -disk-limit 5MB -soft-disk-limit 3MB -threshold 5MB"